# Kohana ORM проблема из названием столбца таблици

Tags: orm, kohana

В общем возникла ошибка при выводе списка товаров из категории:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'products_categories.categorie_id' in 'where clause' [ SELECT `product`.`id` AS `id`, `product`.`title` AS `title`, `product`.`description` AS `description`, `product`.`price` AS `price`, `product`.`available` AS `available`, `product`.`image_id` AS `image_id` FROM `products` AS `product` JOIN `products_categories` ON (`products_categories`.`product_id` = `product`.`id`) WHERE `products_categories`.`categorie_id` IS NULL ]
```

Как выяснилось если поменять названия в связаной таблице в БД с categories_id на categorie_id то все работает. Но теперь перестает работать добавления, редактирования, удаления товара из БД. Получается для одного случая подходит одно названия столбца а для второго другое названия. Можно ли как то исправить на уровне исправления в php коде, а не в самой БД.

Модель категория и модель продукт выглядит следующим образом.

```
class Model_Product extends ORM{

    protected $_table_name = 'products';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_db_group = 'default';

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'categories' => array(
            'model' => 'categorie',
            'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
            'through' => 'products_categories',
            'far_key' => 'categories_id',
        ),

        'images' => array(
            'model' => 'image',
            'foreign_key' => 'product_id',
        ),
    );

    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'main_img' => array(
            'model' => 'image',
            'foreign_key' => 'image_id',
        ),
    );

    class Model_Categorie extends ORM_MPTT {

    protected $_has_many = array(
        'products' => array(
            'model'   => 'product',
            'through' => 'products_categories',
        ),
    );
```

Вывод списка товаров из БД:

```
class Controller_Index_Catalog extends Controller_FrontPage {

public function action_cat(){
    $cat = (int) $this->request->param('cat');
    $categories = ORM::factory('categorie')->where('id', '=', $cat)->find();
    $products = $categories->products->find_all();

    $content = View::factory('/index/catalog/catalog_cat')
                ->set('cat',$cat)
                ->set('categories',$categories)
                ->set('products',$products);
    $this->template->content = $content;
    $this->template->title = $categories->title;
}

}
```

Ругается на строку:

> $products = $categories->products->find_all();

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с именованием таблиц и ключевых полей. Нужно придерживаться определённых правил:

1. Таблицы все называть во множественном (plural) числе, исходя из правил английского языка: таблицу с категориями - categories, с товарами - items. Если нужно - использовать префиксы.
2. Primary_key в таблице пишите как название таблицы в единственном числе + '_id'. Для категорий - category_id, для товаров - item_id.

А вообще, почитайте как правильно всё именовать.

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно сказали :-)
Вот, почитайте: [ORM — Русская документация Kohana 3](http://ru.scribd.com/doc/100759596/ORM-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-Kohana-3)
и ещё 
[Стиль кодирования](http://kohanaframework.su/guide/coding_style)
Там достаточно, чтобы понять.:-)

Comment: Спасибо. Ссылки сходу не нашёл =)