# Проблема с названием поля при формировании запроса

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Доброе время суток уважаемые,
Сразу скажу, что на подобный вопрос с ответом, я уже наткнулся на [этом сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/320373/kohana-orm-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D1%86%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8?answer_sort=oldest), но я хотел его немножко расширить, неким образом.
Вопрос в следующем:
Получается так, что при формировании запроса, в нем каким-то образом, может учавствовать **наименование класса**?,

При разборке урока «*ШП - Kohana Framework от А до Я*», а именно формирования запроса «соответствия продукции, какому-нибудь из каталогов» (страничка например «http://www.kohana/catalogC/cat/2» (в моем случае)), я столкнулся с проблемой, некорректного формирования (в запросе) названия одного столбца, а именно "`category_id`" в таблице «`products_categories`».
К названию столбца прибавилась буква «m», и столбец в запросе стал называться "`categorym_id`".

У меня в проекте все названия файлов с модулями, заканчивается соответствующей буквой «**М**» (например «categoryM.php», «productM.php»), мне так легче в коде ориентироваться, что ни как не противоречит [link text](http://ru.scribd.com/doc/100759596/ORM-%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-Kohana-3).
Вот пример неудачного запроса:

```
Database_Exception [ 1054 ]: Unknown column 'products_categories.categorym_id' in 'where clause' [ SELECT productm.id AS id, productm.title AS title, productm.description AS description, productm.cost AS cost, productm.status AS status FROM products AS productm JOIN products_categories ON (products_categories.product_id = productm.id) WHERE products_categories.categorym_id = '2' AND status != 0 ]
```

**Без** буквы «m» (в "`categorym_id`"), все РАБОТАЕТ, а также РАБОТАЕТ, если переменовать файл "categoryM.php" в "category.php" (с соответствующей корректировкой в файлах проекта).
В файле "productM.php" связующее поле (ключ) указано верно, `'far_key'  => 'category_id'`: (Во всяком случае, это **одно место, где указывается это поле** для формирования запроса)

```
class Model_productM extends ORM 
{
   protected $_table_name = 'products';
   protected $_primary_key = 'id';
   protected $_db_group = 'default';
   protected $_has_many = array('comments'    => array('model'      => 'commentM',
                                                       'foreign_key'=> 'product_id',
                                                        ),
                                 'categories' => array('model'      => 'categoryM',
                                                       'foreign_key'=>'product_id',
                                                   'through'=>'products_categories',
                                                       'far_key'  => 'category_id',
                                                        ),
                                );

    public function count_products()
    {
        return DB::select('id')->from('products')->execute()->count();
    }

      //validate data
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
                     'title'        => array(array('not_empty'),
                                       array('min_length', array(':value', 3))
                                            ),
                     'description'  => array(array('not_empty'),
                                            ),
                     'cost'         => array(array('not_empty'),
                                       array('numeric'),
                                            ),
        );
    }

    public function labels()
    {
        //message (translate) about error
        return array('title'        => 'Name',
                     'description'  => 'Description',
                     'cost'         => 'Cost',
                    );
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return array(TRUE   => array(array('trim'),
                                    ),
                     'title'=> array(array('strip_tags'),
                                    ),
                     'cost' => array(array('strip_tags'),
                                    ),  
                    );
    }
}
```

Не подскажите, как исправить данную проблему, Может быть, можно как-то явно задать название (например как с названием таблицы, с помощью «`protected $_table_name`»), но такого в описании, я не нашел.

Comment: Пришел к 2-м вариантам решения:<br>
1. Или класс нужно переименвать с "categoryM" на "category" (наименование класса учавствует в формировании запроса)
или
2. в таблице "products_categories", переименовать поле с "category_id" в "categorym_id"

Answer (score 1):

По-умолчанию `far_key` задается так:

```
$defaults['far_key'] = Inflector::singular($alias).$this->_foreign_key_suffix;
```

Т.е. единственное число от названия + суффикс ("_id")

У меня есть только одно предположение, вы используете старую версию Коханы, где этот параметр еще не был добавлен, либо он почему-то игнорируется. Надо лезть в отладку и выяснять.